# ted devito datepicker question

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I can't figure out how to change the format for this and there is nothing really in the sparse documentation, which I find bizarre since it is surely one of the most important things when dealing with date inputs.

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#event_start").simpleDatepicker();
});
</script>
```

http://teddevito.com/demos/calendar.php

I don't know what he means by:

> allows you to easily change the
>   output format (look for
>   "jQuery.fn.simpleDatepicker.formatOutput
>   = function (dateObj) {...")

If anyone can point out what I'm not seeing I would be massively grateful, i really need to change this format!

Comment: Just so you know, you can simplify your script a bit (assuming you don't have another plugin using the dollar symbol - $). You can do something like: $(function() { $('#event_start').simpleDatepicker(); });

Comment: The reason I am doing that is because it is inside a wordpress admin page and I don't want any conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is referring to this code which is in cal.js:
`jQuery.fn.simpleDatepicker.formatOutput = function (dateObj) {

return (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dateObj.getDate() + "/" + dateObj.getFullYear();};`

That's the code you need to change.

Comment: Ah I see, I can just change those around then. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have tried changing those around and it won't output a value.